# Activity finish when I change the orientation of the screen

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation-changes

I've searched for a solution to this problem and have not found anything. The problem is that I have created an activity and I want this to change the orientation of the screen when the user displays a dialog. The activity has started with the portrait orientation, which is defined in the *AndroidManifest.xml* to not be able to change when the user rotate the screen, it only changes the orientation when the user presses a button to show the dialog. But when this happens, the activity changes the orientation, but once changed it is closed. I have checked the logcat, but does not throw any exception.

This way I have defined my activity in the *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.BarCodeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_barcode"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

And this is the code I use to change the screen orientation at that time:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    Log.e(TAG, "onSave startDialog: " + startDialog);
    state.putBoolean("startDialog", startDialog);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle state) {
    startDialog = state.getBoolean("startDialog", false);
    Log.e(TAG, "onRestore startDialog: " + startDialog);
    if (startDialog) {
        showDialog();
    }
}

private void showDialog() {
    Log.e(TAG, "creating dialog");
    Dialog barcodeDialog = new Dialog(BarCodeActivity.this);
    barcodeDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
            startDialog = false;
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    });

    barcodeDialog.setContentView(R.layout.code_dialog);
    barcodeDialog.setTitle("Scan barcode");
    ImageView barcode = (ImageView) barcodeDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_barcode);
    barcode.setImageDrawable(barcodeDrawable);
    TextView codeView = (TextView) barcodeDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_code);

    codeView.setText(code);
    /*barcodeDialog.show();*/
}
```

When the activity will start again and then closes, I have seen that in the logcat output strange, if not you will have something to see, I've been researching but I have not had luck with the solutions. This is the output:

```
08-01 19:21:21.600  31521-31521/com.my.app W/ResourceType﹕ Failure getting entry for 0x7f090058 (t=8 e=88) in package 0 (error -75)
08-01 19:21:21.600  31521-31521/com.my.app W/ResourceType﹕ Failure getting entry for 0x7f090058 (t=8 e=88) in package 0 (error -75)
08-01 19:21:21.610  31521-31521/com.my.app D/not﹕ got -1
08-01 19:21:21.610  31521-31521/com.my.app D/not﹕ got -1
08-01 19:21:21.620  31521-31521/com.my.app D/not﹕ got -1
08-01 19:21:21.630  31521-31521/com.my.app D/not﹕ got -1
```

What can be the error?

If it helps I have updated the Android Studio to 1.3 version.

Comment: use android:configChanges="orientation" in android manifest file

Comment: As per your logcat it seems to be It is a resource problem. I am having the same Warning message because Android SDK (eclipse) stopped support to generate icons for res/drawable-ldpi. And the testing device is one with a smaller screen which requires low DPI icons. According to Google, 9.9% of the devices are ldpi and this number is decreasing over time.

Comment: @MustakimurRahman I have tested it, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
        <activity
          android:name=".ui.BarCodeActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_barcode"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
           <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value=".ui.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

to

```
        <activity
          android:name=".ui.BarCodeActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_barcode"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
           <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value=".ui.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

and test with this code in your activities.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Does not work, I have the same result, the same logcat.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but when you use configChanges you must define both orientation and screensize as shown below if you support all the versions of android else [take a look at this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Therefore, change **android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"**

to

**android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"**

and it should work because we use that in our app.

Hope, this helps someone.